# What is the problem in my js and Html codes?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML codes**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <label > Enter Your Age:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter your text"><br> 
  <button type="submit" id="mySubmit">Submit</button><br>
  <p id="resultElement"></p>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**JS codes**

```
const myText = document.getElementById("myText");
const mySubmit = document.getElementById("mySubmit");
const resultElement = document.getElementById("resultElement");
let age;
mySubmit.onClick = function(){
  
  age = Number(myText.value);
  if (age >= 100) {
    resultElement.textContent ="You are too old to enter this site.";
  }
  else if (age == 0) {
    resultElement.textContent ="You are too young to enter this site.";
  }
  else if (age >= 18) {
    resultElement.textContent ="You can enter this site now.";
  }
  else if (age < 0) {
    resultElement.textContent ="You are not a human.";
  }
  else {
    resultElement.textContent ="You can only this site enter when your age crosses 18.";
  }
}
```

I am just a beginner in JavaScript. So i don't know where i am facing problem in these code.

Please help me to find the error. I am using google chrome as browser and vscode as code editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the onClick with onclick:

mySubmit.on**c**lick = ...

Happy learning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).